# Adicionar itens no topo da RecyclerView com FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase

Como faço para adicionar itens no topo de uma `RecyclerView` usando o `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`?

Por padrão, sempre que adiciono um item, ele vai para o final da lista do RecyclerView, e quero que ele vá para o inicio.
Lembrando que esse adapter é diferente do padrão do Android.

```
noteAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteHolder>(Note.class, R.layout.note_item, NoteHolder.class, dbRef) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(NoteHolder viewHolder, final Note model, final int position) {
                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setContent(model.getContent());
                viewHolder.setColor(model.getColorBg());

                model.setId(getRef(position).getKey());

                viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), NoteDetailActivity.class);
                        it.putExtra(Note.NOTE_PARCE, model);
                        startActivity(it);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        notesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        notesRecyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
```

**UPDATE:**
Pesquisando sobre, vi que esse `adapter` pega as informações exatamente como estão no `firebase`, incluindo a ordem, então eu teria que inserir já na ordem certa no `firebase`, mas como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método estático `reverse()` da classe [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). Como no seu código não contem onde resgata os itens da lista, vou dar um exemplo básico abaixo:

```
    ArrayList<String> actores = new ArrayList<String> ();
    actores.add("JON SNOW");
    actores.add("DAENERYS");
    actores.add("KHAL DROGO");
    actores.add("NED STARK");
    actores.add("MONTANHA ");
    actores.add("TYWIN LANNISTER");

    System.out.print(actores);
```

**Saída:**

```
[JON SNOW, DAENERYS, KHAL DROGO, NED STARK, MONTANHA , TYWIN LANNISTER]
```

---

Agora usando `Collections.reverse()`:

```
Collections.reverse(actores);
System.out.print(actores);
```

**Saída:**

```
[TYWIN LANNISTER, MONTANHA , NED STARK, KHAL DROGO, DAENERYS, JON SNOW]
```

Perceba que reverteu a lista em relação a inserção. Sendo assim, basta adaptar às suas necessidades. Para mais detalhes veja [na documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)).

Veja [funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/RgO2hr).

Comment: não estou usando lista, esse adapter já faz tudo, ele retorna o objeto que eu quero, mas não guardo isso em uma lista, e não se usa lista nele, esse é o problema, ele faz tudo... Mas preciso usar ele para o recyclerview

Comment: @felipe.rce O que é esse dbRef então?

Comment: variavel do DatabaseReference, não é uma lista, é coisa do firebase... Eu até tentei usar list para manipular a ordem, mas não da, o firebase coloca aquilo mesmo, única solução é na hora de inserir no firebase... Inserir na ordem certa, mas já pesquisei muito e não vi nada sobre